# Trying to route traffic through a tunnel server error: "Nexthop has invalid gateway"

Tags: networking, openvpn, routing

Short version: we have servers in another data center and we have an openvpn tunnel between them.

For the first time, I need to hang server on a different subnet from the tunnel server and I'm getting killed trying to add a route.

Box A: 10.129.78.101
Box B: 10.129.68.80 (This is the tunnel server)

For all other 10.129.68.X boxes, adding a route through 10.129.68.80 was easy peasy. Here I'm having a problem. I've added a route to 10.129.68.80 and I can hit it no problem. When I try to use it as a gateway for another route it's puking:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.129.78.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens32
10.129.68.80    10.129.78.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens32
10.129.78.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 ens32
```

Try to add a route and puke city:

```
ip route add 10.0.8.0/22 via 10.129.68.80 dev ens32
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use gateway from different network, always from your. See here https://serverfault.com/a/953230/92276. But with OVPN you can achieve many scenarios incl. client specific configuration.